# Page template Macro expansion failed

Tags: plone

I am trying to make a page template for my dexterity product using summary_view as a starting point. However customising summary view or coping the body of summary view into my type's template yeilds:

```
Macro expansion failed
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'standard_view'
```

Is there a problem with this path, or do I have to do something else to make this template available:

```
<metal:block use-macro="context/standard_view/macros/content-core">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `macros` method to your BrowserView.

```python
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile


class MyView(BrowserView):

    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('my-template.pt')

    @property
    def macros(self):
        self.template.macros
```